# How do i write equation for a lognormal graph if I have 100 points on the graph that clearly have shape of a lognormal graph and the x any are known?

Tags: modeling

Days 1 to 100 are along the x-axis.  The y-axis has the PDF values such that the area under the graph is 1. (x,y) is known for each point. The points line up in a near perfect lognormal distribution by inspection. Days or x can be extended to 200 or more if necessary.  What is the equation for this graph?  More importantly,  how do you find the percentage area from 0 to x days. Do you first have to "normalize" the graph and how do you do that.

Comment: Welcome Joseph. Would you mind to add a picture of your graph to the question? It is super easy, just copy paste. And dont delete the new text line that is added automatically. That would help understanding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have 200 points on a graph (x,y).  All the values for x and y are known.  x starts from 0 to 200.  y's are PDF's generated elsewhere ranging from 0<y< 1.   The 200 points trace out a perfect lognormal distribution graph.  How do I find the area under the graph from x = 0 to x = c,  c is an integer less than 200.  The total area under the graph is 1.

Comment: A "PDF" is a density *function,* so the y-values cannot possibly be PDFs.  If they are *values* of some PDF, they can be anything greater than or equal to $0:$ they aren't necessarily limited above by $1.$  It is exceptionally unlikely that the $(x,y)$ values would be *perfectly* known from a dataset, suggesting this is not a statistical problem at all, but one of mere curve fitting.  That can be performed in many ways by optimizing some measure of distance between curves as a function of the lognormal parameters.

Comment: Thank you.  The graph in question is generated by the orthogonal cross-section of a series of parallel bell curves,  each generated at a different x.  The bell curves define a definite value for the the PDF generated for y on that bell curve.   So x and y are known, and they trace out a perfect lognormal graph.  So now I know (x,y) for 200 or more points.  I am interested in find the area under the graph from 0 to some value X.